# Using WPF to handle events from JavaScript hosted in WebBrowser control

Tags: javascript, wpf

I have a WebBrowser control hosted on a WPF page.  I'm wondering if there is any way for a JavaScript function to call an event in the WPF program.

I have a button on the web page in the WebBrowser control:

```
<button style="height:100;width:100" id="initButton"  onclick="alert('hello');" />
```

In the WPF code, I've tried to hook an event on a button this way:

```
        mshtml.HTMLButtonElementEvents_Event iEvent;
        iEvent = (mshtml.HTMLButtonElementEvents_Event)ele;
        iEvent.onclick += new HTMLButtonElementEvents_onclickEventHandler(ClickEventHandler);
        ...

    private bool ClickEventHandler()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("WPF Event Handler");
        return true;
    }
```

and then call the onclick from my javascript function like this:

```
function SomeEvent(sender, e) {
    alert('JS event handler');
    document.getElementById("initButton").onclick();
 }
```

The WPF code is called when I press the button but not when onclick is called from SomeEvent.

Is there a simpler way to do this?  Is there a better way to call the onclick event from JS so the attached WPF attached event is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The `WebBrowser` control has an `ObjectForScripting` property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx

javascript can call methods on that object, which can call methods on your wpf page to fire events, etc.

Answer (score 1):

ObjectForScripting *is* the answer.  For convenience sake, here is a link to a Winforms example (I too am using WPF, but there is no example on the WPF page):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting(v=vs.110).aspx

For what it's worth, it did not work for me to set my main window as the ObjectForScripting.  I don't think you can use any kind of FrameworkElement object as your ObjectForScripting.